# How to get to a local file in servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I setup Tomcat server locally and I placed my text file in my C drive (c:\test\myfile.txt).

In my servlet, I specify the exact path to the file to read it. I successfully do that.

My question is, where should I place the txt file before deployment and  how can I navigate to it to read it?
I did a test and ran on my local Tomcat

```
System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
              System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

and it showed me the Eclipse folder! maybe because  I run tomcat through eclipse. So I am sure there is either a spcific folder for data or maybe I should create one somewhere in the file system but I need to the relative path.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's your choice. There are basically three ways:

Put it in the classpath, so that you can load it by `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()` with a classpath-relative path:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties"));
```

Here `filename.properties` is supposed to be placed in one of the roots which are covered by the default classpath of a webapp, e.g. `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib`, `Webapp/WEB-INF/classes`, `Appserver/lib` or `JRE/lib`. If the propertiesfile is webapp-specific, best is to place it in `WEB-INF/classes`. If you're developing a project in an IDE, you can also drop it in src folder (the project's source folder).

You can alternatively also put it somewhere outside the default classpath and add its path to the classpath of the appserver. In for example Tomcat you can configure it as shared.loader property of `Tomcat/conf/catalina.properties`.

2.) Put it somewhere in web folder (the project's web content folder), so that you can load it by `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()` with a webcontent-relative path:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/filename.properties"));
```

Note that I have demonstrated to place the file in `/WEB-INF` folder, otherwise it would have been public accessible by any webbrowser. Also note that the `ServletContext` is in any `HttpServlet` class just accessible by the inherited `GenericServlet#getServletContext()`.

3.) Put it somewhere in local disk file system so that you can load it the usual `java.io` way with an absolute local disk file system path:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("/absolute/path/to/filename.properties");
```

here are many different ways but it depends on your needs:

To load a property file from `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf directory` you will need to access it using a `java.io.File` object since the class loader (as in `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)` is just able to load files (and classes) from your class path (under `WEB-INF/classes`, `WEB-INF/lib` or `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`).

The easiest example to load a file from the `Tomcat's config directory` would be:

```
File configDir = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "conf");
File configFile = new File(configDir, "myconfig.properties");
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(configFile);
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(stream);
```

Comment: Thank you. But why do you keep using properties? I want the file path as I need to pass it to 3rd party library. I don't want it loaded to properties

Answer (score 1):

Place your config file under your webapp WEB-INF/classes folder and read like this in code

```
InputStream is= 
   YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("myfile.txt");
```

You can also try these other option if you want in JSP.

```
String myfile=
  application.getRealPath("myfile.txt"));

or

String myfile =
  getServletContext().getRealPath("myfile.txt"));
```

Comment: Thank you. But I generate war file so how can I put it in classes folder