# Eclipse: Getting the path for the current project through code? Sevlet, web application

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to get the workspace folder of my current project dynamically. I tried

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

But it doesn't give me the workspace folder of my current project. It only shows the path of my eclipse. Can I get the path of my workspace without plugins or what?

Comment: What you mean by `without plugins or what?`. Are you developing plugin?Question is not clear, re frame the question.

Comment: I mean without the use of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 File file = new File(".");//current workspace directory from where eclipse runs java.
 System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
 Output:
 <WorkspaceDirectory>\<projectName>
```

Comment: What do you mean? I tried to do it also by using `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` but I was getting the metadata which is the backup right? I mean for the preferences. I just want the workspace like `C:\Eclipse\Workspace` something like that

Comment: Did you ever mentioned you are using web application? Update you code what application it is and how are you trying to get the path.

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes I am using web application, servlet. I'm trying to get the path of my folder somewhere in my desktop

Answer (score 0):

From an Eclipse plug-in you could write

```
String location = Platform.getLocation();
```

where Platform needs to be imported like this

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;
```

This would get you the location of your Eclipse workspace and you can work out the project from there by adding the project name to the path.

However you seem to want to obtain this location from the context of your servlet. Can you please explain why you need this? Servlets executing on Tomcat should not really access local files on the disk, because if you want to deploy them on a different server, you would not find consistent behaviour.
For instance, if you need your servlet to access some files from your workspace, the best is to add them as resources to your web project as part of the web content.

You should probably also check this question (although you may have done it already):
[How to get to a local file in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236036/how-to-get-to-a-local-file-in-servlet)

If this is not pointing you to the Eclipse workspace, it is probably because you are not launching Tomcat from your Eclipse, but rather using an external Tomcat instance. Is this correct?

Comment: I just want to get the path of my workspace so I can create a folder (if not existed) since I am creating a web application that will create a pdf file which means having to have a separate folder containing the pdf files will make it more better. I don't want to copy and paste the path of the local disk because it's too long for me

Answer (score -1):

Try to change run configuration --> argument.
it should work.