# How can I run a normal java class using a servlet?

Tags: java

I have a java class which takes a .txt file and convert it into pdf file the problem is I want to call this java class in servlet its not happening.

I tried it out in a few ways which didn't work for me.

Comment: There are multiple ways to run your servlet. Basically you can have a client to invoke your servlet. Clients could be html/jsp, another servelt, a junit test class, etc. the only thing you need to keep in mind is mocking / passing appropriate arguments

Comment: My java class is text2pdf and i tried to access it in a servlet called servlet1 by creating the instance of the class text2pdf i.e text2pdf obj=new text2pdf() ,and tried to call the main method since i dont have any parameters to pass i got error

Comment: You have to make a Minimal, complete and verifiable example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: //This is my textpdf class

Answer (score 0):

Servlet is a server component and it is running on your application server. It is no longer a normal java file that runs in its own jdk. See the answer to the below, should help you get going. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25236114/4433695